# iOS In-app purchases for multiple videos

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my application, i've multiple videos to be displayed and users have to pay for each video to view it. I'll be picking the videos list from server. Means I can add any number of videos on the server. The problem is that, I don't want to add a new non-consumable bundle id to Apple Dev account for each new video added to server.(Lot of work) At the same time, I cannot have consumable ids which don't match my requirement. Need some guidance on how to implement in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use consumable in app purchase for this. Once user purchases and you the video is displayed, then you can make this particular purchased video to be accessible by this user by maintaining a boolean value in the database of your user. Now again if user taps to watch the purchased video, then you can check if user have purchased this video, if yes, you can show video else start in app purchase.

Comment: Will it be objected by Apple? Because users can delete the app and install again or user has moved to a new iOS device or may be having 2 iOS devices like iPhone and iPad........

Comment: For this you will have to add restore mechanism in the application by which user can restore his previous purchases..

Comment: my question is about the same. If its consumables, how to restore previous purchases?

Comment: If you are using consumable products you cannot restore it. The trick you can use is just to save product recipt with that userId and check for it wherever you require. But I suggest to use non consumable product for this.